# Efficiently get kth smallest element in unsorted list in python

Tags: python, algorithm, list

Is there any fast/efficient method available for solving this problem?

I can do it in `O(nlogn)` but faster solution I am expecting.

Comment: Will downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm), which is done in `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the Python libraries you might try [heapq.nsmallest](http://pymotw.com/2/heapq/).

Comment: `heapq.nsmallest` is `O(n + k log n)` time. While this is better than the `O(n log n)` time original algorithm, it is way worse than a proper selection algorithm. In special, `heapq.nsmallest` uses  `O(k)` additional memory, which is really unnecessary.