# Find the 10 smallest numbers in a large dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, pseudocode

I am coding specifically in python, but right now in the phase of designing psuedocode for an algorithm that will take all the data points in a data set that has n values, n being very large and pick out the 10 smallest values (or finite number m << n, where m is the m smallest numbers). I wish to have an optimally efficient algorithm for the requirements.

My idea:

1) Heapsort the data then pick the smallest 10 values. O(nlog(n))

2) Alternatively,use a loop to identify a 'champion' that runs 10 times. With the first 'champion' determined remove from the dataset and then repeat this loop. O(n) (given m is small)

Which suggestion or if there is another would be best?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently get kth smallest element in unsorted list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326372/efficiently-get-kth-smallest-element-in-unsorted-list-in-python)

Comment: No scaling of my problem is different. I do not want arbitrary k smallest values, I want k such that k << n. This affects complexity.

Comment: Sure, but you can trivially substitute k into those complexity expressions: heapselect and selection are both O(n) if k is constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach among many possible:

Grab 10 values and sort them. Now compare the largest with the 11th through nth values one at a time. Whenever the new value is smaller replace the 10th smallest with it and resort your 10 values.

The list of 10 values, sorting them etc will all be in cache so fast even with rough code. The whole list will be accessed once through so will be fast as well.

Comment: Interesting solution, but do you happen to know what complexity it will run at?

Comment: It's O(nk). You can get it down to O(n log k) if you store everything in a heap, but you should benchmark to see if it's worth the overhead.